# How to allow smooth scrolling in all browsers

Tags: html, css, web, scroll, overflow

I have recently noticed that when you have a div containing overflowed content that is scrollable, in chrome, you can smoothly transition scrolling from that div to the rest of the body, but in Safari, you can not. Instead of smoothly transitioning, the scrolling stops when you reach the top or bottom of the contained element, and you must scroll again to begin scrolling on the body. It is vital to the project I am working on that I allow Safari to scroll smoothly the same way Chrome does. For the life of me I can not figure out how to do this. Any input is appreciated, thank you for your time!

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. Your code is usually the best way people can help you. See [minimal, complete, verifiable article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can try my go to settings for a CSS element that is scrollable. Although I can't help you too much without seeing your code, try implementing these:

```
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; 
  overflow-y: scroll;
```

I usually apply these for iOs devices and it does the trick. Not 100% sure if it will help your problem.

Comment: It will not work properly for iOS since the browser can only scroll one element at a time, **not two consecutively** like Silas indents to do.

Answer (score 0):

Safari separates scroll gestures for different elements on purpose so that the user can clearly tell what element is being scrolled.

Of course, you can use JavaScript to solve this in a hacky way. For example, you can set the `ScrollTop` of `body` to the amount that the user scrolled when the **div** has reached to the bottom.